# How to GET request from PC to get list of all MR for my gitlab project

Tags: macos, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I am trying to get all of merge requests and generate a report out of it.
When I am looking though documentation I do find a command for it here

GET /projects/:ID/merge_requests?state=al

But when I am using it in my terminal getting warning saying GET command not found ..any help would be appreciate and thanks in advance.

Comment: Show how you are "using it in [your] terminal", i.e. what exact commands you try to run, how, and what exact errors you get. If you are just trying to type `GET` as a command and expect it to work, it won't: you will need to run some other program that knows how to communicate over HTTP first. Or just use your browser or some other GUI to load the GET URL and retrieve the results. Or write a compiled/interpreted program that uses some HTTP library to do this... etc.

Comment: I think u are right , I am just going in project root folder and tried that command then it says GET command not found.. any docs how to use browser to get this?

Comment: a GET request is equivalent to just typing the specified address in the address bar of the browser and pressing Enter or clicking Go or whatever... and plenty docs on how to do GET requests in a variety of other ways exist out there, but requesting docs is off-topic for SO.

Comment: I don't think I am looking for url here .. I just want to generate pdf report of my project MR's ..

Comment: A GET request is an HTTP request, and an HTTP request is run against a URL...